# Set context path irrespective for WAR version name in Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, contextpath

I am using Maven to build our application.
So the war name will be `MyTest-1.00-SNAPSHOT1.0` .If I deploy the same in Tomcat I have use the URL as

```
//localhost:8080/MyTest-1.00-SNAPSHOT1.0
```

but I need to set the context path MyTest eventhough deployed WAR name as `MyTest-1.00-SNAPSHOT1.0`.
I need the URL will be

> //localhost:8080/MyTest

always even though the WAR name has version or etc.

Suggest me to achieve this scenario.

Comment: You have to create war file with the name MyTest.war

Comment: @atishshimpi No .Eventhough the deployed WAR file name has version and snaphot , I need to use the Mytest as context path when hit the URL

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to directly generate the war file with name `MyTest.war`. To do so you can use `finalName` in the `build` section:

```
<build>
    <finalName>MyTest.war</finalName>
    ...
</build>
```

**EDIT**: (to add more information resulting from the comments)

AFAIK there isn't anything that we can include in the war that automatically sets a context that is not related to the file name.

from: [Apache Tomcat 7 Configuration Reference - The Context Container # Naming](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming)

> When `autoDeploy` or `deployOnStartup` operations are performed by a
>   Host, the name and context path of the web application are derived
>   from the name(s) of the file(s) that define(s) the web application.
>   Consequently, the context path may not be defined in a
>   `META-INF/context.xml` embedded in the application and there is a
>   close relationship between the context name, context path, context
>   version and the base file name (the name minus any .war or .xml
>   extension) of the file.

Also says:

> If you want to deploy a WAR file or a directory using a context path
>   that is not related to the base file name then one of the following
>   options must be used to prevent double-deployment:
>
> - Disable `autoDeploy` and `deployOnStartup` and define all `Contexts` in `server.xml`
> - Locate the WAR and/or directory outside of the Host's `appBase` and use a `context.xml` file with a `docBase` attribute to define it.

But has the disadvantage of having to update the configuration for each new version.

As you use Maven, maybe an option is the [Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html) to deploy the war. It allows to configure a differente context path (*I've never used this plugin*):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <path>/mycontext</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

from: [Tomcat Maven Plugin Usage](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: I dont want to change the created WAR name.It will as it as  with version and sanpshot.but I need to know after the deployment i need to use static context name eventhough chnages in deployed war.

Comment: Then you have to disable `autoDeploy` and configure the context yourself. But you will have to update it for every new version. If `autoDeploy` is enabled the `context` is derived from the filename.

Comment: I am not using autodeploy.I tried to put context.xml in meta.INF but not working

Comment: Is there any way to define the context.xml in java config.Our application is based on Spring config.I just want to know is there any way to define context.xml in appconfig

Comment: AFAIK there isn't anything that we can include in the war for that. Maybe you can use the tomcat maven plugin, I can't think of anything else. *(I edited my answer to include the reference to the plugin)*

Comment: I am able to copy context.xml from app/META.INF to Tomcat conf/catalina/localhost/appname.xml  but still not able to hit the URL with the path

Answer (score 1):

In your server.xml you add the context under `<Host>` :

- docBase = "fileName.war"
- path = "/path"

Int your case would be 
`<Context docBase="MyTest-1.00-SNAPSHOT1.war" path="/MyTest" reloadable="true"/>`